# Ajax to call external .php AND script on click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make ajax to call an external php site (imageslider.php) and an additional script when clicking a menu item (.imageslider). 
Calling the .php works perfectly, but the script (js-image-slider.js) already fires up when starting the main page! And since I have like 7 menu items, each with different scripts, I'd like to have them loaded with $.getscript instead!
Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.imageslider').on('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
        $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'0' }).empty();
    }
    $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'2000px' },function() {
        $('#loader').css({ border:'none', position:'relative', top:'24px', left:'48px', boxShadow:'none' }); 
        $('#ajax').load('imageslider.php ' + href, function() {
            $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow').colorFade({ 'fadeColor': '#0e0e0e'});
        });
    });
}).click(); // calls imageslider initially without clicking it, because it's the main page
});$.getScript('/js/js-image-slider.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add *null* as second argument

```
$('.imageslider').on('click', null, function(){
// code
});
```

Comment: I added null, but it did not work. I must add that I really am a noob at this :/
I am guessing the $.getScript('/js/js-image-slider.js');  should come earlier in the script somehow?

Comment: remove getScript at all, and add in the top, after jquery attached <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js-image-slider.js"></script>

Comment: but then it loads when the inital site loads and not when I click my menu item

Comment: but does it work at all now? we can add onload action in second step... :)

Comment: It works, but it loads the image-slider.js before I click .imageslider. it's supposed to load it together with imageslider.php when I click it in the menu

Comment: I think it is not good idea to load '/js/js-image-slider.js' each time you click a menu item... Can you post you code to jsfiddle.net to see in action what is going on ?

Comment: I have 7 menu items. each with jquery scripts. I do not want to load them at all once, but only when needed!

Comment: In this way you have to add $.getScript('/js/js-image-slider.js'); inside onclick function and write 7 IF statements to load needen JS file instead /js/js-image-slider.js

Comment: hmmm, thanks for your help! :)
I don't know yet how to do that, but maybe I can find it online. or do you roughly know how to code it?

Comment: I think it will be too hard for you... If a could have all your page with all scripts, of course I can

Comment: Wow, I think I made it! it looks weird though. is it malpractice?
     <a class="blog" href="#Imageslide" onclick="javascript: $.getScript('/js/js-image-slider.js' , function (){ youFunctionCall() ; } );" />Imageslider</a>

Comment: Brilliant! Nice and simple )